In the Multiplatform compse of kotlin called my custom function of swift
I'am use jetpack generate project

common main
interface Platform {
    val name: String
}

expect fun getPlatform(): Platform


iosMain realize
class IOSPlatform: Platform {
    override val name: String = UIDevice.currentDevice.systemName() + " " + UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion
}

actual fun getPlatform(): Platform = IOSPlatform()

I hopes it passes swift code realize.
class IOSPlatform: Platform {
    override val name: String = UIDevice.currentDevice.systemName() + " " + UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion
}

let kotlin called swift code.
import Foundation
import UIKit

@objc(iOSPlatformImpl)
public class IOSPlatformImpl: NSObject {
    @objc
    public static func getSystemInfo() -> String {
        let systemName = UIDevice.current.systemName
        let systemVersion = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
        return "\(systemName) \(systemVersion)"
    }
}

I know not how called
